# Construction project data

Tags: data-request, government

I'm working on a project where I'd like to compare rates of construction job postings with known construction projects in an area.

Is there a database of known construction projects in any given areas? For example, schools, buildings, and roadwork should have public RFPs, right?

Comment: Any region of particular interest (i.e. the entire US, a State, or a city)?

Comment: I am looking for the most comprehensive aggregation available, focusing on the US

Comment: government construction projects will most likely have an RFP in whatever the 'newspaper of record' is for their area.  But I'd be more inclined to ask at either the local planning office, or whatever group handles construction permits/inspections.